# React.js material table edit single cell only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

I have a material table like so...

```
   import MaterialTable from 'material-table';

   <MaterialTable
      className="material-table"
      title="Cabinet Properties"
      columns={labelValueTableConfigFixed}
      data={cabinetProps}

      cellEditable={{
          onCellEditApproved: (newValue, oldValue, rowData, columnDef) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              console.log('newValue: ' + newValue);
              setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
            });
          }
      }}
      options={{
        search: false,
        sort: false,
        exportButton: false,
        paging: false
      }}
      icons={tableIcons}
    />
```

The `cellEditable` makes all cells editable but I actually only want one cell to be editable. How can I achieve this? I know how to turn off editable for a column but not for a single cell within a column.